# Could I measure code coverage (Sonar + JaCoCo + Maven) of many modules from one test folder?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a problem with code coverage(Sonar + JaCoCo + Maven + Selenium (integration tests)).
Here is my structure of project.

```
+-[CLIENT] 
|  +-[src]
|      +-[main]
|      +-[test]    <= Unit tests
+-[SERVICE] 
|  +-[src]
|      +-[main]
|      +-[test]    <= Unit tests
+-[TESTS] 
|  +-[src]
|      +-[main]
|      +-[test]    <= Integration tests
```

Could I measure code coverage of "CLIENT" and "SERVICE" modules by Integration tests in "TESTS" folder?

Answer (score 0):

May be this post can help you:
http://www.lordofthejars.com/2012/07/jacoco-in-maven-multi-module-projects.html

My suggestion:
You can run all test and record them in the same jacoco execution data file.
But when you create the report for each project, only the classes of this project will be used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Jacoco needs the class files of the tested classes to create the report, which in your case are not available (because they are in different module). Here is a post which presents a solution to this by making the sources available with the maven-source-plugin. It uses ant, which is not an option in my case, but maybe it helps you:

http://olafsblog.sysbsb.de/measuring-test-coverage-of-integration-tests-for-separated-modules-with-jacoco/